# Data Tracking For Process Improvement

Tags: machine-learning, data, google-cloud-platform

I work in a manufacturing plant with 6 production lines. As part of the maintenance crew, it is my job to record all maintenance work performed on the equipment inside of our shared OneNote. This information only gets reviewed a couple of times before it is never looked at again. I want to use google cloud to extract the text and look for equipment trends over time in order to better identify recurring problems. I have limited coding knowledge and I have been watching videos and poking around the google cloud services but I feel pretty lost. If anyone could advise me as to which tools would be best for this, that would be greatly appreciated. I have been trying to use Document AI but I've completed the process of labeling and testing my data and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Thank you and apologies if this is not the correct forum for this.